# Windows Forms disappear in visual studio 2013 ultimate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This is what i am doing:

-Creating a new project

-Adding multiple forms

-Adding service-based database

-Adding multiple tables in SBD

-Adding Ado.Net Entity Data Model

-Choosing EF designer from database

-Choosing the database (.mdf) and saving the connection to the app config (both by default)

-Choosing all the tables

-Finish

-Now forms disappear from solution explorer, if i try to add new it says existing form is located with the same name, if i try to add existing it does nothing.

When i open them from explorer, i am getting these errors http://prntscr.com/77hma2

Additional info : AvtoriiKnigi.Avtori translates to English as AuthorsAndBooks.Authors if you need a translation.

I reinstalled the IDE still not fixed.

Visual Studio set to update from windows update and is max updated.

Windows 8.1 max updated.

SQL server installed and management studio 2012.

These infos came in mind right now, if you need other info feel free to ask.

Thanks

Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was posted long time ago but the solution was solved by Microsoft itself, i fired a bug report and they fixed it.

Comment: If you can provide a link to the MS connect Id displaying this issue's tracking then it will be of great help for the readers.

Comment: i lost the password for the account that i fired the report, sorry